# How can I manually adjust menu colors in themes?

Tags: unity, themes

I am using Ubuntu 14.10 with the Unity interface and the Ambiance theme. I like this theme, and any other theme I've tried was much worse for me. However, one thing that really bothers me with this particular theme (it's not like that in others) is that the menus are hardly readable, with very dark background *and* foreground colors.

I would like to manually edit the CSS file(s) defining the theme and change the menu colors. Can anyone point me to the specific color definition (there are quite a few)?

A solution using a fine-tuning tool might also be acceptable, though generally I prefer to get in there and do it myself.

Note: I've read elsewhere that this might be a bug resulting from me also installing KDE. This doesn't seem to make sense, but even if that's really the case, uninstalling KDE is not an option as I sometimes use it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems my problem was not with the theme files (as proven by the fact nothing changed when I replaced them with the files from a friend where everything was working normally), but in ~.config/gtk-3.0. Removing this directory solved the issue.

Until shown otherwise I'll assume menu colors can **not** be adjusted in the theme files. For posterity, please do add an answer regarding manually adjusting menu colors in theme files if you have one (and I'll accept it if it's good).

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue after installing kde in parallel with ubuntu 14.04. Menus was hardly readable, with very dark background and foreground colors. **Problem was resolved with deleting file ~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini**. This file doesn't exist yesterday (acording to  yesterday copy). Before deleting I tried to find cause of problem in /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/ but that folder wasn't changed.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/540599)

Comment: @Pilot6 How is this not an attempt at answering the question?